# Inkscape change font size units from "pc" to "pt"

Tags: inkscape

When creating text in Inkscape my font units used to be in pt, that is the convetional 12pt that might be used in a Word document. One day it changed to "pc", and the default size is now 1 pc (similar to around 12pt). How do I change it back to pt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit > Preferences > Tools > Text: Text size unit type : Point

or

Double-click on text tool icon > Text size unit type : Point.

Comment: I don't have such option. I have the same setting dialog as shown in the John Edwards' answer.

Comment: Yes, it has been removed. As far as I know, Inkscape now just remembers your setting. Does it not?

Answer (score 0):

not available on my prefs, what am I doing wrong (IS v1.1)?[image: snip]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/110386)